# Truncated incorrect INTEGER value on CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I get this error([Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'Z001'), when create temporary table vacunas2. I'm using MySql

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vacunas AS (
SELECT h.COD_ESTAB,stb.DESC_ESTAB,h.DNI,h.FECHA_NAC,h.FICHAFAM,h.ED ,DIA,MES,
  ANO,EDAD,TIP_EDAD, ESTABLEC,DX1,DX2,DX3,DX4,DX5,DX6 
FROM `hisa` h
inner JOIN establec stb
on stb.COD_ESTAB=h.COD_ESTAB
where h.ANO='2020' and ('1' or '2' in (h.MES)) AND h.ED='61');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vacunas2 AS (
SELECT * FROM vacunas
where 'Z001' OR 'Z006' or '99403' or 'U140' OR '99401 'IN (DX1,DX2,DX3,DX4,DX5,DX6)
order by DNI,FECHA_NAC ASC);


SELECT * FROM vacunas2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not make sense:

```
where 'Z001' OR 'Z006' or '99403' or 'U140' OR '99401 'IN (DX1,DX2,DX3,DX4,DX5,DX6)
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
WHERE 'Z001' IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6) OR
      'Z006' IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6) OR
      '99403' IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6) OR
      'U140' IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6) OR
      '99401' IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6)
```

Comment: They have a similar issue with `'1' or '2' in (h.MES)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well. Just out of curiosity, why did the first way to use IN work well the first time(I used it like simple query, without temporary table)?


('1' IN (h.mes) OR
'2' IN (h.mes)) is right?

Comment: @Freddy my guess would be the string value `'1'` casts to an integer one, which then evaluates to true; so it ends up being `true or '2' in (h.MES)`. So while it didn't end up being considered a syntax error, the query could have returned undesired data.

Comment: Well, so far it is working fine, however, what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: @Freddy `'1' in (h.MES) or '2' in (h.MES)` or alternatively `h.MES in ('1','2')`